# redirect cookie after logging in, how to deal with forms?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post, cookies

I'm saving the current URL of a user in `$_COOKIE['redirect']` on every PHP page a guest user is allowed to be. But on each page there's also a login link. When the user clicks on log in, he's taken to a login page that - after successful authentication - redirects the user to the last page he was on,  by referring to `$_COOKIE['redirect']`.

This is all working perfectly fine, except that one of the pages where a user can choose to go to the log-in page, is a page that he has reached after *submitting a form* on the previous page.

So when the user is redirected to that page, it's missing the information needed to populate from the previous page's form, and so it shows broken links, etc.

So it's like this:

1. User is on page 1, and submits some info via "post" to page 2.
2. User is now on page 2, and decides to use the "log in" link, which takes him to login page.
3. The login function authenticates the user, and then redirects him to where he was before logging in, i.e. page 2.
4. Since page 2 no longer has the info passed onto it from page 1, it's messed up, with missing links and text, etc.

Apart from restructuring the way I'm doing everything, is there any solution for this? Anyway the redirect URL can somehow also remember the important info posted via the previous page?

Comment: Why don't you save the POST information in another cookie? Serialize the data when the form is posted, and when the user is redirected to that page, you unserialize the cookie and fill the form.

Comment: I'm checking up on jquery cookie and serializing/unserializing data, so far I've come up with this: `$.cookie('my_form', $('#designform').serialize());`. But how to unserialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet is this ..

**Scenario :**
the user comes to page 2 after submitting some data .
And your cookie will redirect him to that page

**Solution:**
So rather than resubmitting the data again (which i guess is useless) simply redirect the user in page2 to page1 if he doesnt have the required data..

And this needs to be done for sure because What if the user directly types in the URL of page2 ..i.e,without the post data).. Even then you get this problem. So the above solution stops this from happening